# Unity 5.3.3 UI does not exist in namespace

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference, namespaces

So I have been working on a Unity project for a while and since a few weeks ago every time I try to attach visual studio to Unity I get multiple errors. All of the errors I get are to do with 'UnityEngine.UI'

```
CS0234  The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I have not edited the solution file at all, I have no changed any references either.

Now what is strange is when I build get a list of errors, however If I double click one it takes me to the error location and then all the errors disappear like the solution is fine. However if I then build the project I get all the errors back...

The only way I think you can reproduce this error is make a new Unity project (I'm using 5.3.3f1), create a script and include this namespace

`using UnityEngine.UI;`

Then see if you can build the project. If anyone knows a solution to this project that would be awesome :)

Also in my "Warning" window I have these 3

`The primary reference "UnityEditor" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Unity Web v3.5".`

`The primary reference "UnityEngine.Networking" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Unity Web v3.5".`

`The primary reference "UnityEngine.UI" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Unity Web v3.5".`

Comment: That just causes a crash where it can't find more stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your last build target was "Web Player".

1. Open: File->Build Settings...
2. Choose PC, Mac & Linux Standalone
3. Build your game - during this step the VS solution settings will be fixed